# How to move a div containing a image

Tags: css

I cant seem to move the image inside a div.  It can only be moved with absolute positioning, which I am not okay with. Can someone point out why the below given code isnt working. I want all 3 divs to be in one line . Image seems to be stuck in the top left corner. Applying padding doesnt change anything either.Please help

```html
<div class="container" style="display:table">
  <div style="display:table-cell">
    <div class="emblem" style="padding:0 0 0 20px ;display:table-cell"></div>
    <div class="logo" style="display:table-cell" Software Solutions</div>
    </div>
    <div class="header" style="">
      <nav>
        <ul style="display:flex;justify-content">
          <li><a href="{% url 'signin2' %}" target="ifr" ONCLICK="setTitle1()"> Home</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="{% url 'aboutus' %}" target="ifr" onclick="setTitle2()">
              <title>RCE-About</title>About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'products' %}" target="ifr" onclick="setTitle3()">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'contacts' %}" target="ifr" onclick="setTitle4()">Solutions</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'contacts' %}" target="ifr" onclick="setTitle5()">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what this `justify-content`?(I mean you did not set any declare to this)

Comment: Mainly because you're using table layouts. display:table is never a good way to go, except whem you're building tables and even then <table> would be better. Table destroys most layout flows.

Comment: @לבנימלכה [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)... not sure why it's just sat by itself though.

Comment: Use a more modern display type like flex or grid; `display:table` is pretty archaic nowadays.

Comment: Can you suggest a way without tables then ? display:flex;justify-content:center

Comment: Seems to be an ">" forgot before "Sofware solutions".
But is it maybe easier using display: flex; justify-content: space-between; to the container of your logo.

Comment: 1. Where is your image ? 2. Your html has a few issues, unclosed tags, title tags wrongly placed, etc. 3. Which 3 divs to you want to on one line ?

Comment: its a typo . sorry

Comment: emblem , logo , header .Those 3 in one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's maybe something like this you need to do..

EDIT:edited snippet code, navbar is under logo but take 100% width

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
 
  background:gray;
  padding:5px;
}
.navbar-container{
  width:100%
}
.container > div{
  display:block;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding:15px;
  text-align:center;
}
ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
ul li{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="1">Some text</div>
  <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
  <div class="navbar-container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li>test1</li>
        <li>test2</li>
        <li>test3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I put emblem and logo in one line and the header in the second line